# Wordpress, the portfolio page is using the heading 'Blog Archives' and I want it to say 'Portfolio'

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Wordpress site, when I click on my Portfolio Category, it shows the title 'Blog Archives' which is not what I would like.

I would like a title of 'Portfolio' . So I've found the template file for archive.php , and it basically says if the variable is_Day, is_Month or is_Year is set, then show the relevant archive title, else show 'Blog Archive' , see the code below

```
<h2>
    <?php if ( is_day() ) : /* if the daily archive is loaded */ ?>
  <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>' ), get_the_date() ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_month() ) : /* if the montly archive is loaded */ ?>
  <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>' ), get_the_date('F Y') ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_year() ) : /* if the yearly archive is loaded */ ?>
  <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>' ), get_the_date('Y') ); ?>
<?php else : /* if anything else is loaded, ex. if the tags or categories template is missing this page will load */ ?>
  <?php _e('Blog Archive', 'theme5820'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</h2>
```

It appears to me that the Portfolio page is using the archive template to display posts, because above it says 'if anything else is loaded, ex. if the tags or categories template is missing this page will load'

So my question would really be, is it ok to just change 'Blog Archive' to Portfolio, or should I create a page for the portfolio category, as the portfolio pages themselves show the title ok.

Cheers, Rich :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see if there's a `category.php` template. If so, copy it to `category-portfolio.php`; if not, copy `archive.php` to `category-portfolio.php`. Then edit the new file and remove whatever header code you don't want (if there's a `category.php` the code may be somewhat different from `archive.php` since it would be more specific to category displays). WP will automatically use the new template when you select the `Portfolio` category.

(I'm assuming this is in your own theme. If not, create a child theme, put the new file there, and select it. That way you won't get burned if your current theme is upgraded).